# mixed multiple extensions and file match with POSIX regex

Tags: regex, posix

I'd like to match all files with extensions .xml, .csv and all files named liveinfo.txt with POSIX regex.

Could you please help out? I know if I had a single extension I could use `"\.acf"`.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html):

```
'\.xml|\.csv|liveinfo\.txt'
```

For example:

```
grep -E '\.xml|\.csv|liveinfo\.txt'
```